# MySql count column based from same table

Tags: mysql, select

This type of questions already asked but that is not solve my problem.

I have table called `scraping_data`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id        | accountId | label         | subLabel  | status|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         | 1         | Application   | Nice      | 1     |
| 2         | 1         | Application   | poor      | 1     |
| 3         | 1         | Application   | Nice      | 1     |
| 4         | 1         | Chennal       | Quality   | 1     |
| 5         | 1         | Application   | Nice      | 1     |
| 6         | 1         | Channel       | poor      | 1     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here I want to take counts by subLabel, for Example here `label` **Application** comes 4 times with Nice  times and poor 1 time. And same **Channel** come 2 times with Quality 1 time, poor 1 time.

My output will be like:

`Application Nice count 3 and poor count 1`

query:

`SELECT * FROM scraping_data`

Comment: You are looking for a pivot query, see here: https://www.databasestar.com/mysql-pivot/

Comment: You should add the expected result as table to your post

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the conditional aggregation using `group by` and `sum()` :

```
select label, sum(case when subLabel = 'Nice' then 1 else 0 end) as nice_count,
              sum(case when subLabel = 'poor' then 1 else 0 end) as poor_count
from mytable
group by label
```

Or using `count()` :

```
select label, count(case when subLabel = 'Nice' then 1 end) as nice_count,
              count(case when subLabel = 'poor' then 1 end) as poor_count
from mytable
group by label
```

To dynamically generate pivoted data you can use Prepared statements :

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when subLabel = ''',
      subLabel,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS `',
      subLabel, '_count`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  mytable;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT label, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM mytable 
                   GROUP BY label');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6lXzBf2q)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but here `Nice` and  `Poor` will be dynamic values. Like in subLabel column can have any of the name

Comment: Then you need either a pivot query (like Turo suggested) or, again, [you make it the application's responsibility to transform the results into your desired output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188083/mysql-count-column-based-from-same-table/76188108?noredirect=1#comment134358209_76188108). That's where it *belongs*.

Comment: Its can be done using prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT `label`, count(`sublabel`)
FROM `scraping_data`
WHERE `label` = 'application' -- < optional
GROUP BY `label`
```

[Group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and [Count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer my output will be come like "select label, sublabel, count(sublabel) from scraping_data group by sublabel"

Comment: Any how I getting this query from idea

Comment: It's the application's responsibility to transform the result into your desired output. All you need to do is iterate the result.